# Spring Security JWT REST API returning 401

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt

I have a relatively simple setup using Spring Boot 2, Spring Security, and I'm using JWT to essentially keep users logged in.

The full project is here:  http://github.com/mikeycoxon/spring-boot-2-security-jwt

I have two filters, one, does authentication, the other authorization.

I have an AuthNFilter:

```
public class AuthNFilter extends UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter {
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    public AuthNFilter(AuthenticationManager authenticationManager) {
        this.authenticationManager = authenticationManager;
    }

    @Override
    public Authentication attemptAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
                                                HttpServletResponse res) throws AuthenticationException {
        try {
            User creds = new ObjectMapper()
                    .readValue(req.getInputStream(), User.class);

            return authenticationManager.authenticate(
                    new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(
                            creds.getUsername(),
                            creds.getPassword(),
                            creds.getRoles())
            );
        } catch (IOException e) {
            throw new RuntimeException(e);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest req,
                                            HttpServletResponse res,
                                            FilterChain chain,
                                            Authentication auth) throws IOException, ServletException {

        String token = Jwts.builder()
                .setSubject(((User) auth.getPrincipal()).getUsername())
                .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + EXPIRATION_TIME))
                .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, SECRET.getBytes())
                .compact();
        res.addHeader(HEADER_STRING, TOKEN_PREFIX + token);
    }
}
```

This verifies the user against a data store and adds a custom header to the response with the token.

and an AuthZFilter:

```
public class AuthZFilter  extends BasicAuthenticationFilter {

    public AuthZFilter(AuthenticationManager authManager) {
        super(authManager);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest req,
                                    HttpServletResponse res,
                                    FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String header = req.getHeader(HEADER_STRING);

        if (header == null || !header.startsWith(TOKEN_PREFIX)) {
            chain.doFilter(req, res);
            return;
        }

        UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken authentication = getAuthentication(req);

        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        chain.doFilter(req, res);
    }

    private UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken getAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request) {
        String token = request.getHeader(HEADER_STRING);
        if (token != null) {
            // parse the token.
            String user = Jwts.parser()
                    .setSigningKey(SECRET.getBytes())
                    .parseClaimsJws(token.replace(TOKEN_PREFIX, ""))
                    .getBody()
                    .getSubject();

            if (user != null) {
                return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(user, null, new ArrayList<>());
            }
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Which replaces the BasicAuthenticationFilter so that we can read the JWT and set up the user in the SecurityContext.

For this to apply, I set up a WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter so that we could override spring security's defaults:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;
    private BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder;

    public WebSecurity(UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsServiceImpl, BCryptPasswordEncoder bCryptPasswordEncoder) {
        this.userDetailsService = userDetailsServiceImpl;
        this.bCryptPasswordEncoder = bCryptPasswordEncoder;
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(SIGN_UP_URL).permitAll()
                .antMatchers(LOGIN_URL).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated()
                .and()
                .addFilter(new AuthNFilter(authenticationManager()))
                .addFilter(new AuthZFilter(authenticationManager()))
                // this disables session creation on Spring Security
                .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(bCryptPasswordEncoder);
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        final UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", new CorsConfiguration().applyPermitDefaultValues());
        return source;
    }
}
```

`SIGNUP_URL` = /api/user and is a POST
`LOGIN_URL` = spring's own /login endpoint

Basically, the problem comes up in the test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
@ActiveProfiles("embedded")
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class AccessControllerFunctionalTest {

    @Autowired
    private WebApplicationContext context;

    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;

    @MockBean
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        mvc = MockMvcBuilders
                .webAppContextSetup(context)
                .apply(springSecurity())
                .build();
    }

    @Test
    public void doSignup() throws Exception {
        String requestString = "{\"username\": \"mike@gmail.com\",\"password\": \"password\"}";
        mvc.perform(post("/api/user").contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(requestString))
                .andDo(print()).andExpect(status().isOk());
    }

    @Test
    public void doLoginFailsWithUserNotExists() throws Exception {
        String requestString = "{\"username\": \"mike@gmail.com\",\"password\": \"password\"}";
        mvc.perform(post("/login").contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(requestString))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isUnauthorized());
    }

    @Test
    public void doLoginSuccessWithUserExists() throws Exception {
        String requestString = "{\"username\": \"rmjcoxon@gmail.com\",\"password\": \"password\"}";
        mvc.perform(post("/login").contentType(APPLICATION_JSON)
                .content(requestString))
                .andDo(print())
                .andExpect(status().isOk())
                .andExpect(header().exists(HEADER_STRING));
    }

}
```

The first two tests pass, the third one fails, which is unexpected. It always returns with:

```
MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = POST
      Request URI = /login
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = {Content-Type=[application/json]}
             Body = <no character encoding set>
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = null

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 401
    Error message = Unauthorized
          Headers = {X-Content-Type-Options=[nosniff], X-XSS-Protection=[1; mode=block], Cache-Control=[no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate], Pragma=[no-cache], Expires=[0], X-Frame-Options=[DENY]}
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []
2018-05-27 19:56:24.868  INFO 8949 --- [    Test worker] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet ''
2018-05-27 19:56:24.868  INFO 8949 --- [    Test worker] o.s.t.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet  : FrameworkServlet '': initialization started
2018-05-27 19:56:24.872  INFO 8949 --- [    Test worker] o.s.t.web.servlet.TestDispatcherServlet  : FrameworkServlet '': initialization completed in 4 ms

MockHttpServletRequest:
      HTTP Method = POST
      Request URI = /login
       Parameters = {}
          Headers = {Content-Type=[application/json]}
             Body = <no character encoding set>
    Session Attrs = {}

Handler:
             Type = null

Async:
    Async started = false
     Async result = null

Resolved Exception:
             Type = null

ModelAndView:
        View name = null
             View = null
            Model = null

FlashMap:
       Attributes = null

MockHttpServletResponse:
           Status = 401
    Error message = Unauthorized
          Headers = {X-Content-Type-Options=[nosniff], X-XSS-Protection=[1; mode=block], Cache-Control=[no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate], Pragma=[no-cache], Expires=[0], X-Frame-Options=[DENY]}
     Content type = null
             Body = 
    Forwarded URL = null
   Redirected URL = null
          Cookies = []

Status expected:<200> but was:<401>
Expected :200
Actual   :401
```

I'm not sure where the /login endpoint comes from, but I'm pretty sure that it shouldn't be getting authenticated like it is, otherwise how does anyone login?

I assume that my lack of understanding of Spring Security is at fault her, can anyone see what I've done wrong?

I asked a similar question before on a different setup - there was little in the way on answers, so I'm trying again.

Comment: Can you put it up on git so that we can take a closer look at it.

Comment: here you go in all its (in)glory: https://github.com/mikeycoxon/spring-boot-2-security-jwt

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Per default spring generates a basic form login. You need to disable it in the Websecurity like so:

```
@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(SIGN_UP_URL).permitAll()
            .antMatchers(LOGIN_URL).permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .addFilter(new AuthNFilter(authenticationManager()))
            .addFilter(new AuthZFilter(authenticationManager()))
            // this disables session creation on Spring Security
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            .and().formLogin().disable();
}
```

EDIT:
After some debugging I found the errors.

1. You have mocked the `UserRepository` but not the method so
   `findByUsername` will always return null. I have removed it to
   use the real repository against the hsql.
2. The user is always locked.

   ```
   @Override
   public boolean isAccountNonLocked() {
       return false; //changed it to true
   }
   ```
3. The password encoder only support version $2a$ from bcyrpt and not $2y$.

After changing these the test runs without error.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion, but it didn't make a difference. I still get the same failure on the same test.

Comment: @MichaelCoxon Finally found some time and solved it.

Comment: thank you so much, that worked. Funny though, just about every online Bcrypt password hasher uses $2y$ and don't say so, or give you an option to change it.